# TFPT unshelve /migrate across workspaces

Tags: tfs-power-tools

Thank you to Ben Cull for providing [the unshelve/migrate instructions in his blog](https://benjii.me/2014/04/move-shelveset-to-different-branch-in-tfs/):

**Problem:**

Unable to unshelve migrate across workspaces

**Setup:**

- Workspace 1, Branch a
- Workspace 2, Branch b
- Shelveset 999

**Execution:**

*using VSDevCmd.bat*

- tfpt workspaces showed that workspace 1 & 2 do exist
- tfpt unshelve /migrate
  /source:"$/project/a" /target:"$/project/b" "999"

**Result:**

"cannot be unshelved because the server path is not mapped in the local workspace"

**Expected:**

"merge was successfull"

**Research:**

I have reviewed unshelve on [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/unshelve-command?view=vsts) and could not find a workspace parameter.

**Question:**

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

### No

This is not possible. You'll need to map both paths in the workspace. Workspace is athe "container" for work in TFVC and there is no command that works cross workspaces.

Comment: I have remapped to a single workspace and found that unshelve migrate works as expected. Thank you.